# How to grant Azure Functions only specific Graph permissions (one sharepoint library)

Tags: azure, sharepoint, azure-functions, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-files

My Azure Functions app shall use Excel input/output bindings. The files are stored on a specific sharepoint document library. I wish to use application permissions, not user-delegated ones.

In the graph documentation there is this

[Files.ReadWrite.All](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/permissions-reference#files-permissions)

Which is too broad for my taste. Can this be narrowed down to only specific folders in a specific sharepoint?

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can this be narrowed down to only specific folders in a specific sharepoint?

No, it can't.

Microsoft Graph does not support this currently, the `Files.ReadWrite.All` application permission is needed in this case.